# How to automatically delete Wordpress comments older then X days

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a website in WordPress with a forum that uses the default comment system.

In my forum page users continuously post comments.  I would like to automatically delete comments that are older then 15 days.

Is it possible to auto-delete WordPress comments on any page that are older than a predefined number of days?

Comment: Run a cron every day at a time your server is not so busy...

Comment: You can but unless there's a plug-in for that then you'll have to write your own - it's pretty easy, a cron job to run a php file maybe daily to delete comments older than x days

Comment: @Raj Please accept and upvote http://stackoverflow.com/a/34721467/2667307 if helped thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any plugins to automate the task.

You can use the following SQL:

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE date_sub(now(), interval 15 day) > comment_date
```

I suggest you create a scheduled cron job to run a script that connects to your database and executes the above SQL everyday.

(Assuming your comments table is named wp_comments.)